# how to show gridlines while export in excel using crystal report in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports in VS 2022 and I want to export my data in excel format. Wanted to show data with gridlines but its not appearing.
Tried this
ExcelFormatOptions excelFormatOpts = new ExcelFormatOptions ();
excelFormatOpts.ShowGrideLines = true;
gridlines are visible but columns get merged.
Can someone please help me out in this.
Thanks in advance.

Tried this
ExcelFormatOptions excelFormatOpts = new ExcelFormatOptions ();
excelFormatOpts.ShowGrideLines = true;

Need gridlines without column merging.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to save the desired export options in the rpt file.
In Crystal Designer, open the rpt file and go to
***File, Report Export Options...***

Select your export format and set the export options for that format. Then, save the rpt file.

You can also set the options in code, but the approach above is simpler.